# Hibernate TypeBootstrapContext not found

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am trying to map java enum to PostgreSQL enum in Spring app. I am doing completely same things as Vlad did in his [tutorial](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-an-enum-type-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) (Section *Mapping a Java Enum to a database-specific Enumerated column type*).

So I've imported `hibernate-types-55` artefact, added

```java
@TypeDef(
   name = "pgsql_enum",
   typeClass = PostgreSQLEnumType.class
)
```

Above entity class, added

```java
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "column_name",
        columnDefinition = "some_enum",
        nullable = false)
@Type( type = "pgsql_enum" )
private SomeEnum someProperty;
```

and finally added a column with newly created database enum where values corresponds with values in enum

But I am getting

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.type.spi.TypeBootstrapContext from
```

while trying to start the application using Wildfly.
Whole maven build completes successfully, all tests passed, so everything looks okay but this exception which causes app wont start at the server.

The Hibernate core version I am using is `5.2.10.Final`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I´ve imported hibernate-types-55 artefact

As it's stated in the [documentation](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types#hibernate-54-53-and-52), you should use:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.0</version>
</dependency>
```

for the Hibernate 5.2 branch.